# add properties of QLineEdit to QTable Widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add a `Table Widget` in my application. But some properties which I want are not supported for `Table Widget`, but are available for `QLineEdit`.
For example `Validator`, `PlaceHolderText`, etc properties from `QLineEdit`. I want to have these properties for individual cells of `Table Widget`. I don't want to add `QLineEdit` in my `GUI`, only `Table Widget`.
Is it possible to do this?
Thank You.

Comment: May be create a custom object inheriting from the Qt objects you are wanting to use.

Comment: I think, you can change those cells to be a `QLineEdit` and use its functionality.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai can you please show some code?
I dont know how to create such an object.

Comment: @MM. can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass that draws the text or placeholder text as normal (it can do this without reimplementing), but produces a `QLineEdit` as it's editor widget.

Add it using `QTableWidget::setItemDelegate(QAbstractItemDelegate* delegate)`.

Comment: so should I create a QLineEdit object say lineObj;
Then pass it as editor through QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(lineObj);
Then I can set the required properties for lineObj?
But this seems to create an overhead of QLineEdit object & all its signals & slots!
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Some sample code to show how to connect the QLineEdit to QStyledItemDelegate would be very helpful...

Comment: The `QlineEdit` is created when an edit trigger occurs, `setEditorData(..)` 'configures' the widget depending on the data the cell is displaying, then `setModelData(..)` writes the data back to the model from the widget.  **Only one widget is created at any one time.** https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can change those cells to be a `QLineEdit` by [`setCellWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget), and use its functionality :

```
the_table_widget->setCellWidget(row, col, new QLineEdit);
```

Comment: Doing this isn't great for most scenarios: The widget cannot access the model through the MVC interfaces, so any data _for_ and _created by_ the widget must be manually handled outside of the framework.  For any moderately sized table, this strategy can become very inefficient as every cell displaying the data will need a `QLineEdit` created for it (not to mention all the supporting signal/slot connections), even if 99% of the time they are only used to display static content.  There's a reason delegates exist.  Also the cast is unnecessary as `QLineEdit` derives from `QWidget`.